# Can celery return results from all consumers to the producer if we use Fanout exchange type

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, celery-task

I have a celery producer on one host and 4 celery consumers on 4 other hosts. I am using rabbitmq as broker and Exchnage type is "Fanout". Can i get result from all the consumers?

Comment: have you tried enabling results and testing this?

Comment: Yes. I got only one result. I want to get results from all the workers.

Comment: are you sure you have configured your results backend correctly - you say you have rabbitmq as a broker but you don't say what you are using for a results backend. can you post a minimal task and configuration that show the problem clearly?

Comment: Yes, in backend i am using rabbitmq with <br/> Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://password@localhost:5672/vhost', backend='amqp://

Comment: please see my previous comment